# How to get Android to play a high quality RTSP stream smoothly?

Tags: android, video, streaming, rtsp, darwin

Does anybody have any luck streaming a high quality video (over 1000kbps) to Android through RTSP?

We currently have low quality video streams (around 200kbps) that work wonderfully over 3G. Now we are trying to serve a high-quality stream for when the user has a faster connection. The high quality videos play smoothly in VLC, but the Android playback seems to drop frames and get blocky, even on a 4 megabit connection.

It seems like the YouTube app uses a plain HTTP download for their high quality videos. This works well and plays smoothly, but will not work for streaming live videos. Has anybody had luck streaming high quality videos to Android through RTSP?

The videos are encoded using H.264, 1500kbps, 24fps, and a 720x480 resolution. In the app, we are using a VideoView to play the videos. We are using Darwin Streaming Server, but we are open to other options if necessary.

## Update 6/23/2011

Looking through Darwin some more today. So far, I am just logging the request and session information in a Darwin module.

The original Droid tries to use these settings: `3GPP-Adaptation:...size=131072;target-time=4000`. Although that means it wants 4 seconds of buffer, 131Kb only holds about a second of playback at 1200kbps. I understand that 1200kbps is large, but it is necessary for a high quality video (minimal compression on 720x480).

I am trying to force the client to buffer more, but I haven't figured out how to do that yet. I'm just looking through the Darwin Streaming Server source and trying to figure out how they do things. Any Darwin experts out there?

## Update 6/24/2011

As it turns out, using plain old HTTP for viewing videos on demand works well with no loss of quality. When we get to live streaming, we will have to look more into RTSP.

Comment: Hey- could you tell me how you're obtaining HTTP URL's? I'm currently using the YouTube Gdata API (for searching) but am getting very low quality streams; this would be better for me, thanks.

Edit: You're doing your own streaming, nevermind :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well even if the network is able to transmit at that rate, you still need to decode it. What are you using for decoding? You will probably need to use a NEON accelerated video decoder so you can have a proper framerate, and a decent size buffer... the graphics processor is only as good as the bus that it is in... Also what are your encoding settings and resolution?

Edit: You are encoding those at much to high bitrate, half of that will do fine. Also you need to make sure where the issue lies. Is the mediaPlayer getting the data and failing to stream at a decent framerate, in that case you have to replace the MediaPlayer code with your own player. Is it's network issue then only solution is to lower the bitrate, 600Kbps would be just fine (or 500Kbps video, 128Kbps audio), it's 3x your 200k stream and on a screen this small, the difference is not noticeable.

Comment: I added the encoding and resolution to the original post. We are leaving the decoding up to Android's MediaPlayer, which should be using Stagefright, but could also use OpenCore on other devices.

Comment: Unfortunatly the only solution that I worked in Real Time is http://www.tokbox.com/opentok/api/features probably not suitable to your needs. So am actually really interested in seeing what other people have to say.